# Best way to "splice" my update loop?

Tags: java, libgdx

If I'm making a game and I want certain things to only update every so often, what's the best way to approach this?

My naive thinking is just keep a "frame" tracker that cycles via mod. math and update certain things at certain numbers.

Is there a better approach?

Much appreciated!

Comment: Basically you want to set up a timer for your game loop. Exactly how to do this depends a bit on what language you're using.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to fit your game 'loop' into the libgdx system is to assume your `ApplicationListener.render()` method is invoked at some unknown (and perhaps variable) frequency.  In this callback you'll need to figure out how much time has passed since the last call, update any time-dependent actors, and then draw the update.

This means you should make decisions about updating something "every so often" based on actual elapsed time, and not number of frames.

See the accepted answer on this question for some sample code that does this (note the 'getDeltaTime()' calls):
[How to move a sprite with the keyboard keys using libGDX?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5833065/using-libgdx-can-someone-lend-a-hand-on-how-to-move-a-sprite-the-keyboard-keys)