# Can we give sprite.draw in Libgdx position in render() method?

Tags: android, libgdx

Why can't we give sprite.draw in Libgdx position in render() method like this?

```
batch.begin();
sprite.draw(batch,x,y);
batch.end();
```

I'm aware we can give it a setPosition in create() method, but for example I want to move sprite when a key is press, so I need to give the sprite the x and y variables as position in render. How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless you want to use the method B. Naeem mentioned. You can call the `setPosition` inside the render/update method, like this.

```
batch.begin();
sprite.draw(batch);
sprite.setPosition(x, y);
batch.end();
```

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5833065/how-to-move-a-sprite-with-the-keyboard-keys-using-libgdx) is a similar post of yours, might help you out.

Comment: Thank you. I didn't think of putting it in the render() method.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using `sprite.draw()` you can use the `draw` method of the `SpriteBatch` class instead

```
batch.begin();
batch.draw(sprite.getTexture(), sprite.getX(), sprite.getY());
batch.end();
```

When you move your `sprite` on a key press, simply update the x-position and y-position of the `sprite`.

Comment: Hi. I'm also aware of this. So it's not possible with sprite.draw()?